# Java - Why is this bullet point glitchy?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, htmleditorkit, bulletedlist

I have a JTextPane and a JButton as part of one of my projects. The button adds a bullet point to the JTextPane:

```
HTMLEditorKit.InsertHTMLTextAction bulletAction = new
    HTMLEditorKit.InsertHTMLTextAction("Bullet", "<li></li>",
    HTML.Tag.BODY, HTML.Tag.UL);  
JButton bulletButton = new JButton(bulletAction);
```

When the button is clicked, the bullet is created. If you type on the line with the bullet point, then click the button again, 2 bullet points are created. However, if you do not type on the line with the bullet point, and click the button, only 1 is made.

Why does it have this weird creation glitch?

Comment: Do you have a way to print out the source HTML behind the JTextPane in both cases and compare them?  I think the `InsertHTMLTextAction` is probably inserting extra `</li>` or `<li>` to handle mismatched tags.

Comment: I can save it as an HTML then read, and it comes out just as it appears in the JTextPane, 2 <li></li> are created if there is text in between

Comment: You might have to take the question up with the vendor or `HTMLEditorKit`.  Sounds like a bug in their library.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution. I'm running into pretty much the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522022/jtextpane-bullet-with-htmleditorkit-list-not-rendering-correctly-unless-i-do-s

Answer (score 0):

It is partly due to Swing's reliance on paragraphs to do navigation and cursor positioning around the document. Also Swing's handling of HTML is sometimes buggy, believe it or not. Unless you override Swing's default behaviour, there is little you can do.

I answered a similar question over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17522022/jtextpane-bullet-with-htmleditorkit-list-not-rendering-correctly-unless-i-do-s/19738001#19738001), in case you need more details. Look also at Stephane's answer on the same page for alternative implementations. Hope that helps.